# How can I send to Javascript form elements values. Constantly sending one value

Tags: javascript, php, loops, for-loop

```html
<script>
function tikla()
{
 //var radio=document.getElementById('radio').value;
 var d2=document.getElementById('buton').value;
 alert(d2);
}
</script>
<?php 

 for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
 {?>
     <form>
        <?php echo $i; ?>
            <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" disabled="disabled" /> 
           <input type="button" id="buton" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="tikla(this.value)" />
         </form>
 <?php }?>
```

In PHP, I want to send button or text values to Javascript but I can send only one value. I can't see other loop values.

Comment: Because id's have to be **unique**. Use a class and `this` (or the parameter you're passing into `tikla`)

Comment: a new form for each text field and button? ID attributes MUST be unique and if an element is `disabled` it will not appear in the POSTed values.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really the intention to have multiple forms? There is no reason why not of course but you can accomplish what you need, generally speaking, using a single form.

By using a `nodelist` you can iterate through and assign event listeners separately to the HTML - inline event handlers are considered old school nowadays. In this example the event handler is assigned to each button and simply alerts the numeric value assigned to the button ( as in your example ) and also the value and type of the text field to show how you might access it if required.

A quick demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>JS Func</title>
        <style>
            fieldset{border:none;margin:1rem auto}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <?php
            for( $i=1; $i<5; $i++ ) {
                $rand = rand(1,99);
        ?>
                <fieldset>
                    <?php echo $i; ?>
                    <input type='text' name='txt[]' value='<?php echo $i * $rand; ?>' /> 
                    <input type='button' value='<?php echo $i; ?>' />
                </fieldset>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </form>
        <script>
            Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'form > fieldset > input[type="button"]' ) ).forEach( function( bttn ){
                bttn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                    alert( this.value  +' '+this.previousElementSibling.value + ' ' +this.previousElementSibling.tagName )
                }, false );
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you RamRaider, i don't know nodelist thats why i don't understand your codes, but it will learn

Comment: a `nodelist` is a collection of DOM elements returned when using a method such as `document.querySelectorAll('div')` etc ~ that would return a nodelist of div elements....

Answer (score 0):

pass values in function

```
  <script>
function tikla(val)
{
    //var d2=document.getElementById('buton').value;
    alert(val);
}
</script>
<?php 

    for($i=1;$i<5;$i++)
    {?>
        <form>
        <?php echo $i; ?>
            <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" disabled="disabled" /> 
            <input type="button" id="buton" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"  onclick="tikla(<?php echo $i; ?>)" />
         </form>
    <?php }?>
```